# IIS7 URL Rewrite and User Control postback

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting

When a URL redirect rule fires on a page with user controls the user controls are robbed of their child control events. Does anyone have a solution for how to make URL Rewrite and user controls play nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is make sure that negate=true and redirectype=permanent.